# python InlineKeyboardMarkup c emoji

Tags: python, telebot

Подскажите, как вставить в InlineKeyboardMarkup emoji. Я поднял django на котором пользователь сможет создавать данные для бота.
По АПИ бот забирает данные и потом выводит контент для пользователя.

Вот код который

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def exchange_command(message, data=get_main_data()):
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    get_user()
    if message.chat.id not in users:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У разі випадкової помилки скористайтесь\n\n'
                                            '/getchatid - узнать ID Telegram')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Будь-ласка, виберіть наступне меню: \n\n'
                                          '/manu - узнать ID Telegram')
        for item in data:
            repr = item['repr_name']
            id = item['pk']
            keyboard.row(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(item['name'], callback_data=f"{repr}-{id}"))
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            'Будь-ласка, виберіть необхідне меню из нижче представленного списку:',
            reply_markup=keyboard
        )
```

Я пытался просто скопировать emoji и вставить в тестовое поле.
Пытался вставить в формате UTF-8
Выводит обычный текст в 1 варианте, во втором некорректный текст. Но я хочу что бы возле кнопки был ещё emoji и что бы через текстовый инпут в django пользователь вносил самостоятельно тот emoji который ему надо.

Answer (score 1):

всё прекрасно работает

```
key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
key_b = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='1123 ', callback_data='1123')
key.add(key_b)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'inline emoji', reply_markup=key)

key = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
key.row('1123 ')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'reply emoji', reply_markup=key)
```